# Import "pages" could not be resolved

Tags: python, django-models

I am new in learning python and Django, I am following this course from YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4&t=2779s
I've created a two apps (one called "products" and the another called "pages") as I am following the video but when I am trying to import pages in URL file I get this error "Import "pages" could not be resolved" however I can import the products normally please find the attached image
[code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm7Gb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiqJ0.png)

```
from pages import views
from products import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: are both `pages` and `products` scripts in the same directory?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @matszwecja no, pages app in the directory and products app in another directory

Comment: @Friedrich
I don't know how to add screenshot in the comment, so I edit my question and added the image for code structure

Answer (score 0):

So when trying to run the server it would yield an error such as no module named pages? Or is it just the editor indication?
Please provide full project structure with all django files (most importantly where the manage.py is located).
Also quick tip, at the beginning make sure to follow the project structure Django expects, and to properly intialize any new apps with startapp for example.
Quick note: Your imports won't work the way you do them as you use the same name twice (views), meaning after the 2nd import the first views will be overwritten. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
from pages import views as pages_views
from products import views as products_views
```

Comment: when I run the server using "python manage.py run server" the server working fine without error, this error appears only on the visual studio code